# PHP SOAP Client giving error at the time of calling a method "SoapFault exception: [s:Receiver] Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

I am completely new to PHP SOAP . After doing some R&D for my problem I got some links of stackoverflow but didn't get the perfect solution.

Here is my problem :

I am creating a SOAP client that will execute a method called `GetPassword` and It will return an encrypted password with response code '100' if the credentials is correct. In case of wrong credential a response code '101' and the response status will receive.

Here is my code (I am hiding the credentials for security purpose):

```
  $url= "http://bsestarmfdemo.bseindia.com/StarMFFileUploadService/StarMFFileUploadService.svc?wsdl";
  $method = "GetPassword";
  $error=0;
  $client = new SoapClient($url, array('soap_version' => SOAP_1_2 , 'SoapAction'=>'http://tempuri.org/IStarMFFileUploadService/GetPassword'));

  $actionHeader= array();
  $actionHeader[] = new SoapHeader('http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing',
                                 'Action',
                                 'http://tempuri.org/IStarMFFileUploadService/GetPassword');
  $actionHeader[] = new SoapHeader('http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing',
                                 'To',
                                 'http://bsestarmfdemo.bseindia.com/StarMFFileUploadService/StarMFFileUploadService.svc/Basic');
  $client->__setSoapHeaders($actionHeader);


  $param = array('MemberId' => 'XXXXX', 'Password' => 'XXXXXXX', 'UserId' => 'XXXXXXX');

    try{ 
      $info = $client->__call($method, array($param));
      } 
    catch (SoapFault $fault)  { 
          $error = 1; 
         }

   if($error==1) {
       $xml=$fault;
   }else{
      $xml = $info;
     }
   echo($xml);
```

Some couples of days ago I got this error and the error was happening due to the mismatch of parameters. But this time I think the parameters are correct. So may be I am doing some small mistakes.. Please help me to find the mistakes.

If any input needed, please let me know in the comment, I will update.

**Please Note : I tested the wsdl URL with the SoapUI software and it is returning perfectly.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem was with Parameter . Just analyze the structure of the Method `GetPassword` and found that it take only one parameter named 'Param' which is an object and `inside the Param object it is taking the values of MemberId', 'Password' , 'UserId'.`
So just need to change one line of code. 
use

```
$param =array ('Param' => array('MemberId' => 'XXXXX', 'Password' => 'XXXXXXX', 'UserId' => 'XXXXXXX') );
```

Instead of

```
$param = array('MemberId' => 'XXXXX', 'Password' => 'XXXXXXX', 'UserId' => 'XXXXXXX');
```

and the issue resolved.